# How to importrange row data with query based on a formula?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to import specific row data from different sheets using the `IMPORTRANGE` and `QUERY` functions.

The main issue I can't resolve is I need criteria for each sheet.

I have a summary sheet. I'd like to change the date in Cell B1 and have each row A5:A fill with the data from the appropriate sheet.

Summary sheet:

[image: Summary]

Sheet2:

[image: Sheet2]

Sheet3:

[image: Sheet3]

I've tried using the transpose function to fit the query format. But the query is then only based on one cell.

So, for example, the rows in Sheet start at 201930, but show in the 201928 column in the summary.

Here is an example sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1thBOsfmzd0wy3-LVLs0Un9WHb-9gVEwTZaGb7FcPqgg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you almost had it. delete everything you have in **B2:J** on **Sheet1**

paste this in **B2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:1<>"", YEAR(B1:1)&WEEKNUM(B1:1), ))
```

paste this in **B3** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:1<>"", 
 TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(B5:Z="", 0, B5:Z)), ROW(B5:B)^0)) ,))
```

paste this in **B5** cell and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(B$1:$1, 
 {INDIRECT(A5&"!D10:10"); INDIRECT(A5&"!D9:9")}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

actual `IMPORTRANGE` formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(B$1:$1, 
 {IMPORTRANGE("ID_OR_URL", A5&"!D10:10"); 
  IMPORTRANGE("ID_OR_URL", A5&"!D9:9")}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: You are very generous to say I almost had it.  I've not seen ARRAYFORMULA or MMULTI before and the HLOOKUP method is clever. Thanks!

I wonder if you can explain the ROW(B5:B)^0.